# How to extract source code from git pack file?

Tags: git, github

I have an archived git repository in tar.gz format containing .pack file in object folder.

How can I extract source code from it?

Comment: git-archive is just a function to zip/tar a repository/commit - so what exactly is the problem? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive <- documentation.

Comment: One of my partners created a git archive and I see .pack in the tarball file.
After doing some research, I found a way to unpack the .pack file but how can I get the source code of the project?

Comment: What happens when you simply unpack the .tar-file? What does it list? Just the .pack-file, or other files as well?

Comment: It has a buch of folders and one of them is "object" folder containing .idx and .pack file.

Comment: Then I'm assuming this is something like this: http://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/pack

Comment: I unpacked the pack file using git unpack command but it create a lot of folders in .git/object but there's nothing outside of that folder.
How can I get the source code from this now?

Comment: It's probably a bare repository. Access the (base) folder and run `git status`, what's the output? You should be able to clone from it into a new directory if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Packfiles are one of the ways that git stores objects (see "[Unpacking Git Packfiles](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/three/unpacking-git-packfiles)"). From your comments, it looks like the archive contains the contents of the `.git` directory, in which case I'm guessing that the tarball also contains folders like `info` and `refs` in addition to `objects`.

So to get the actual source code, just untar the folder:

```
tar -xvf archive.tar.gz
```

and move the contents to a directory named `.git`. In other words, you should end up with a directory tree that looks like

```
myproject
|-- .git
|   |--objects
|   |  |-- pack
|   |  |   |-- pack-cdfae92.idx
|   |  |   |-- pack-cdfae92.pack
```

That will "create" the repository in your current directory. You can confirm this by running `git status` - it will say that you deleted a bunch of files. To repopulate the directory (ie, "undelete" the files), just run  `git checkout master`.